# How to apply search of products In Ionic Ecommerce App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce App and I have number of products to show in that App but I am not familiar with the search of products in the Ionic App. So I searched a lot and get the searchbar In Ionic.

This is my front.html: I have added the searchbar.

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="mysInput" (ionInput)="setSearchProducts($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

This is my **front.ts** in which I am fetching the products:

```
   searchproduct: any = [];
   mysInput: string;

    getsearchproducts()
  {
    this.restProvider.getproductsforsearch()
      .then(data => {
      this.searchproduct = data;
      console.log(this.searchproduct.msg);
      });
  }

  setSearchProducts()
  {
    this.searchproduct.filter(searproduct => {
      return searproduct.product_name.includes(this.mysInput);
    });
  }
```

The console is array of products. So, I want to apply search for these products using product name. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-searchbar (input)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of searchProducts">
        {{ item.product_name }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>


public allProducts = [];
public searchProducts = [];


constructor() {
    this.getsearchproducts();
}

getsearchproducts(){
    this.restProvider.getproductsforsearch()
      .then((data) => {
        this.allProducts = data;
      });
  }

getItems(searchbar) {
    this.searchProducts = [];

    var query = searchbar.target.value;
    if (query.trim() == '') {
      return;
    }

    this.searchProducts = this.allProducts.filter((value)=> {
      if (value.product_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
}
```

Comment: I am getting my products from the api. In this: this.searchproduct = data; So, Can you please edit the answer according.

Comment: assign api response data to this.searchproduct

Comment: Okay. So, can you please edit the answer and I will mark it.

Comment: its optional parameter don't use

Comment: It is showing all products name initially. When I open the app.

Comment: It is showing the search but initially it is showing all products name.

Comment: first, load the data. when you search product from the data, assigns search data to the new array. that new array load on the page

Comment: But there is one problem is that, When I searched the products and after showing the result and When the cancel the search, it result is still showing. So, Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187471/discussion-between-raghav-and-umesh-j).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very rough implementation of what you need:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-key-up1',
  template: `
    <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let product of searchproductFiltered">
      {{ product.product_name }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v1 {

  searchproduct = [
    { product_name: 'Dark honey 125m', product_price: 25 },
    { product_name: 'Eucalyptus honey 200m', product_price: 55 }
  ];

  searchproductFiltered = this.searchproduct;

  onKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    const filterValue = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;

    if (!filterValue) {
      this.searchproductFiltered = this.searchproduct;
      return;
    }

    this.searchproductFiltered = this.searchproduct.filter(product => {
      return product.product_name.includes(filterValue);
    });

  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytzuon?file=src%2Fapp%2Fkeyup.components.ts